# F#: Span, raise, and the bottom type (or lack thereof)

Tags: .net, generics, f#, bottom-type

After I posted this comment https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/349#issuecomment-1124206512
I'm still feeling I'm missing out...

Sample code reproduced here for the reader's convenience:

```
let spanOfOptString(os: Option<string>) =
  match os with Some(s) -> s.AsSpan()
                | None -> raise(Exception())
```

> error FS0412: A type instantiation involves a byref type. This is not permitted by the rules of Common IL.

So, F# types a no-return function `raise` as `Exception -> 'a` with a free `'a` ("the OCaml way"), and the type variable happened to be bound to a byref type `ReadOnlySpan`, which was illegal. I felt like I was punished for a crime I didn't commit...

I could find a workaround which was something like

```
let checkedSpanOfString(os: Option<string>) =
  match os with Some(s) -> s.AsSpan()
                | None -> raise(Exception())  // 'a = unit
                          ReadOnlySpan.Empty  // both arms: ReadOnlySpan<char>
```

https://sharplab.io/#gist:32b520574fde97de8d7389ab04f64bc4

but IMHO this is somewhat ugly. And I don't think we should expect something equivalent to `.Empty` to be available for *all* byref types? (I don't think I've ever used any other byref types than (`ReadOnly`)`Span`/`Memory` but that's another story)

While F# core team doesn't seem to be moving towards introducing the bottom type to the language (which is perhaps a sensible engineering decision),
does anybody have a better alternative to make this work?

## Update

@chadnt's answer can be inlined to get

```
let checkedSpanOfString(os: Option<string>) =
  let s = match os with Some(s) -> s
                        | None -> raise(Exception())
  s.AsSpan()
```

https://sharplab.io/#gist:a5eab805c539c45048b4072fa7b096c5

Its IL looks much simpler than my original version

## Update #2

This is essentially the same issue as https://github.com/fsharp/fslang-suggestions/issues/872
which originated from https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/5776 filed in 2018, shortly after the release of F# 4.5 with `Span` support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like assigning the string value first seem to solve it.

```
open System

let valueOrRaise = function
    | Some v -> v
    | None -> raise(Exception())

let checkedSpanOfString (os: string option) =
    let s = valueOrRaise os
    s.AsSpan()
```

https://sharplab.io/#gist:2ca959f498be87f1b52212182af237b4

In FSI:

```
> (checkedSpanOfString (Some "foo")).ToString();;
val it: string = "foo"
```

Comment: geez that was really my blind spot...

Comment: Oh, I see the `inref` has nothing to do with it. I'll edit my answer.